# how to read a xls file with phpexcel bundle? in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

The bundle phpExcel provide the way for write xls files, but i don't know how read a file xls with this bundle..
the bundle can be found at the following address : http://knpbundles.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle

Thanks for your help

Comment: You found how read excel file?

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to read a EXCEL file you can find an example in the official doc : 
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Examples/28iterator.php

Code :

```
$phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject();
    $file = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir()."/../web/uploads/import/membres.xlsx";
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        exit("Please run 05featuredemo.php first." );
    }
    $objPHPExcel = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);

    echo date('H:i:s') , " Iterate worksheets" , EOL;
    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
            echo 'Worksheet - ' , $worksheet->getTitle() , EOL;

            foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                    echo '    Row number - ' , $row->getRowIndex() , EOL;

                    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
                    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set
                    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                            if (!is_null($cell)) {
                                    echo '        Cell - ' , $cell->getCoordinate() , ' - ' , $cell->getCalculatedValue() , EOL;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }


    // Echo memory peak usage
    echo date('H:i:s') , " Peak memory usage: " , (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;
```

Comment: $cell->getCalculatedValue() is deprecated, use $cell->getValue()

Answer (score 1):

The ExcelBundle is just a wrapper service around the PHPExcel class.

the bundle service will return a [PHPExcel_IOFactory](http://www.contao-docs.org/docs/PHPExcel/html/class_p_h_p_excel___i_o_factory.htm) with a specific file format expected in input and output (in this case, xls5)

```
 $xl_obj=$this->get('xls.load_xls5')
```

you can use that as a PHPExcel item, so to read a file:

```
  $my_xl_file = $xl_obj->load($fileName);
```

If you go to the [github page of ExcelBundle](https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle), there is exactly the example you are looking for:

> If you want read xls
>
> > $exelObj = $this->get('xls.load_xls5')->load($filename);

Answer (score 1):

Read a file is like create a file

this create an object starting from an xls file:

```
$phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject('origin.xls');
// work on the object adding contents
// then write to a file
$writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel5');
$writer->save('dest.xls');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it just uses the **[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)** library. You can find examples and docs on it's website.

Comment: Thanks but; phpExcel provide several examples of use and the bundle mentioned not provide in your documentation the way of read files xls...